# apt-get seems connected to an old database

Tags: linux-mint, apt

I just installed Linux Mint on a new computer, and when I want to install software with apt-get, it always gets obsolete versions.
For instance it installs OCaml 4.01.0 (latest is 4.02.3) and Opam 1.1.1.1 (latest is 1.2)

It is the same in Synaptic.

How can I install the latest versions ? If possible without doing manually, as I'm not at ease with Linux and would prefer the automatic option for now.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer. For these packages you have to first do:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:avsm/ppa
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the packages which you install using `apt-get` are the latest stable versions which are selected by the distribution developer team.

It's simple: The package file with specified version is placed on the selected repository. If you want to install the latest version, If other repository provided you can [add it to your repo list.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45879/40417). As you also mentioned in your own answer.