# Debian 8 CD 1 installed but no GUI

Tags: debian, gnome, desktop-environment

I thought CD 1 would at least install GNOME, but it didn't install a GUI at all. How can I get a GUI of some form, preferably GNOME?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the minimal install, you should setup `apt` (in `/etc/apt`), and use `apt-get` to install additional programs via the network.  Some do this with only `apt-get`, etc.,  I use [`aptitude`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html#s-aptitude).

Further reading:

- [How to add repository from shell in Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45879/how-to-add-repository-from-shell-in-debian)
- [8.1 What programs does Debian provide for managing its packages?](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html)
- [Debian Package Management](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianPackageManagement)
- [Apt](https://wiki.debian.org/Apt)
- [Gnome](https://wiki.debian.org/Gnome)
- [3.3. Graphical Desktops](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.graphical-desktops.html) (The Debian Administrator's Handbook)

To install gnome or other desktop, you would install a package *group*:

```
apt-get install task-gnome-desktop
```

But first you should configure `apt` (if your minimal install did not do this for you).

Comment: i tryed the Gnome command it didnt work

Comment: That isn't a lot of information...

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal, run the following command:

```
tasksel
```

Choose `Gnome` then validate.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble (Jessie install with CD one only, no desktop) and when I ran tasksel there was no option for Gnome.

1. I added the relevant country mirrors to my /etc/apt/sources.list from https://linuxconfig.org/debian-apt-get-jessie-sources-list
2. then did an apt-get update
3. re-ran tasksel and this time there was loads of desktop options including Gnome

HTH