# add key for repository

Tags: debian, repository, gpg, aptitude

I've looked around a lot and can't seem to find what I need. I have a couple repositories I want to add, and avoid the "won't install from here because it is unsigned" error - so I'd like to download a key and install it.

I've tried this:

https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt#How_to_find_and_add_a_key

specifically, where it talks about Release.gpg, but all I see there is gpgv, which seems more of a verification. The repository online lists like this:

```
Contents-amd64.gz
InRelease
Release
Release.gpg
contrib/
main/
non-free/
```

This suggestion seems to rely on an *.asc file being present, which apparently is not the case here. [How to add a third-party repo. and key in Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332672/how-to-add-a-third-party-repo-and-key-in-debian)

I expected this to be all over the web but I seem to be either missing it or not getting it...

PS: This is one of my attempts:

```
sudo gpgv --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg ftp://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/stable/orel/latest/repository/dists/orel/Release.gpg ftp://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/stable/orel/latest/repository/dists/orel/Release

gpgv: can't open 'ftp://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/stable/orel/latest/repository/dists/orel/Release.gpg': No such file or directory
gpgv: verify signatures failed: No such file or directory
```

PS2: and another attempt:

```
sudo apt-key adv ftp://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/stable/orel/latest/repository/dists/orel/Release.gpg

Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.hffJ18K2Zz/gpg.1.sh ftp://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/stable/orel/latest/repository/dists/orel/Release.gpg
gpg: can't open 'ftp://mirror.yandex.ru/astra/stable/orel/latest/repository/dists/orel/Release.gpg'
```

Comment: Hi, yes, I installed both Debian keyrings. Still no luck...

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment because I realised it didn't apply. You're trying to install the Astra distribution, correct? The Debian keyrings are for Debian, not Astra.

Comment: Ahhhh yes, for AstraLinux Orel latest. Thought maybe they covered some Debian variants, though I didn't research it.

Comment: The Astra web site is currently not working, but if you have a contact email for them, I suggest you write and ask about their apt key.

Comment: Good idea! I'll do that