# Error when use: sudo apt update on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, terminal

i got this error when i run: `sudo apt update` in terminal on ubuntu 22.04

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Provessor/xUbuntu_20.04  InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 876292BF7F9C32BF
W: http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Provessor/xUbuntu_20.04/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 876292BF7F9C32BF
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried to fix the problem with the following command : `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 876292BF7F9C32BF` but it doesn´t work and got this message

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.fbmSbmsKSu/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 876292BF7F9C32BF
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
```

click here for more details:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sehEd.png

Help me please :(

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem with these comands:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
sudo apt-get update
```

:)

Comment: **This is the nuclear option.** It removes all of your nonstandard repositories, and in some APT systems, removes the standard ones as well. It does _not_, however, remove the GPG keys you've previously added, which may be a security liability (see [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/711640/87770)).

Comment: I'd rather rename the folders (or zip them and then remove the files). Then do the update. Then put the files back.

Answer (score 0):

This method was [deprecated](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/01/apt-key-is-deprecated-how-to-add.html) for [security concerns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582853/87770): it allowed any signing key you've added to sign *any* package, not just those within that signing key's repository.

The safer method is to add the key to a location like `/usr/share/keyrings/repository-name.gpg` and then reference it from your `sources.list` file, e.g.

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/some-repo.gpg] http://some.repo/apt dev main
```

Learn more about [the `sources.list` file format](https://askubuntu.com/a/1396167/260416) or see [this example](https://github.com/Xpra-org/xpra/issues/3485#issuecomment-1104608647) that adds the Xpra key and repository.