# Switching repositories in Debian 8

Tags: debian, repository

Looking for a solution to switch repository from CD to mirror ones, without going to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and changing the content to Internet mirror list.
IMHO It is an absolute waste of time to do it just for one or two applications not included in the CD repo...

Similar as in `yum`, for instance

```
yum install --enablerepo=repository_name_here package_name
```

anything similar in Debian ?

Comment: Why not just keep the Internet mirror in the sources list all the time but **after** the CD ones. When downloading it should use the first available repo. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/135339/assign-highest-priority-to-my-local-repository

Answer (score 1):

There are eight (8) CD:s for Debian Jessie, unless you happen to have them all, it's likely to be more than one or two applications that will not be found on the CD. Also, using a network mirror gives easier access to point releases, and you should probably get security updates from a network archive anyway.

Also, if you use a network mirror when installing, you don't need to edit `sources.list` to add it.

But, see also: [How to add repository from shell in Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45879/170373)

Comment: have 3 DVD version, but there is no VNC server on them, But in general I'd like use CD repo, to save traffic... and even for security updates, every time editing /etc/apt/sources.list  ... silly ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` command to disable/enable urls on your `sources.list`

to disable all `urls` :

```
sed -i '/debian.org/s/^/#/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

To enable all `urls` :

```
sed -i '/debian.org/s/^#//g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Change `debian.org` string with yours.

Answer (score 0):

This script should do, it will back your current repo file
and will create an alias, 
so  you can enable disable repos by commands:

To enabel cd repo:

```
cd-repo-enable
```

To enable net rep:

```
net-repo-enable
```

Script:

```
# backing up
if [ ! -f "/etc/apt/_back.sources.list_back" ]; then
cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/_back.sources.list_back
fi && 
# creating repo file for net
cat <<"EOF" >> /etc/apt/sources.list_net
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
EOF
# creating cd repo file
cp /etc/apt/sources.list cp /etc/apt/sources.list_cd

# enable cd-repo
cat <<"EOF">> /usr/local/bin/cd-repo-enable.sh
rm -fr /etc/apt/sources.list
cp /etc/apt/sources.list_cd /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
EOF
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/cd-repo-enable.sh

# enabling net repo
cat <<"EOF">> /usr/local/bin/net-repo-enable.sh
rm -fr /etc/apt/sources.list
cp /etc/apt/sources.list_net /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
EOF
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/net-repo-enable.sh 

# Removing old alias "net-repo-enable" if detected
sed -i 's/alias net-repo-enable=.*//g' /root/.bashrc
cat <<"EOF">> /root/.bashrc
alias net-repo-enable='/usr/local/bin/net-repo-enable.sh'
EOF
# Removing old alias "cd-repo-enable" if detected
sed -i 's/alias cd-repo-enable=.*//g' /root/.bashrc
cat <<"EOF">>/root/.bashrc
alias cd-repo-enable='/usr/local/bin/cd-repo-enable.sh'
EOF
# Applying changes
source ~/.bashrc
echo "Installation sucess"
```