# how to fix "sudo: apt-repository: command not found" in Deepin distro

Tags: repository, ppa, deepin

what I want to achieve is to install Firefox beta channel to update the current version so after running this command

```
sudo apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
```

I got this error

```
sudo: apt-repository: command not found
```

I've searched a lot to fix this, I found to fix this is to install

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

which is printing the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-software-properties is already the newest version (0.96.9debian1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

and I've tried what is mentioned in this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45879/how-to-add-repository-from-shell-in-debian) and nothing worked.
I can't find any solution for this.

Comment: @arochester nothing solved my issue from the mentioned thread

Comment: So, you installed the 'software-properties-common' package and tried the command I gave below? What distro and version are you using, btw?

Comment: @Time4Tea 'software-properties-common' gives me the same error, and 'python-properties-common' is already installed I'm using Deepin 15.4.1

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
```

I believe that is the correct command.

Comment: this is causing the same error

Comment: What do you get if you type: which add-apt-repository ?

Comment: nothing .. it runs with no message printed

Comment: It prints nothing at all? No output or error? Bizarre. What about if you try 'which grep' or 'which cat' (something that should obviously work)?

Comment: finally something appeared it prints /bin/grep

Comment: try 'which add-apt-repository 2>&1' (redirects standard error to standard output, just in case the error message isn't getting printed to the terminal)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67918/discussion-between-mohamed-ibrahim-and-time4tea).

Comment: `apt install software-properties-common`

Comment: @Bahamut I was talking to him in chat and software-properties-common didn't seem to be in his distro's package list.